# Loop over tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

Is there a way to loop over items in a tkinter listbox, so I can check the first part of an item and delete and replace it with a new item if the two strings match?

for instance if I had:

```
{'breakfast':['bacon','eggs','beans'],
 'lunch':['ham', 'cheese', 'bread'],
 'dinner':['Steak','Potato','Vegetables']}
```

and this was displayed in a listbox using string formatting to:

```
breakfast: Bacon, Eggs, Beans
lunch: Ham, Cheese, Bread
dinner: Steak, Potato, Vegetables
```

if I change `breakfast` to `['Cereal', 'Milk']` how would I change the entry in the listbox **If I didn't know the index**, and only had the dictionary key to go on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Listbox`'s [`get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.get-method), [`delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.delete-method) and [`insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.insert-method) methods, together with `enumerate` to get the index.

Assuming you did `from Tkinter import *`:

```
for i, listbox_entry in enumerate(my_listbox.get(0, END)):
    if listbox_entry == old_breakfast_string:
        my_listbox.delete(i)
        my_listbox.insert(i, new_breakfast_string)
```

If you did `import Tkinter`, replace `END` with `Tkinter.END`.

In fact, if you're looking for an exact match (and you know the element is in the Listbox for sure), you don't even need an explicit loop, instead you can just use Python lists' `index` method:

```
i = my_listbox.get(0, END).index(old_breakfast_string)
my_listbox.delete(i)
my_listbox.insert(i, new_breakfast_string)
```